# "Explain how it is different" and "This solved my question" buttons gone after editing own question flagged as possible duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Is there anyway I can see those buttons again?

And what do the buttons supposed to do?

Here is my guess: First one will let you show a message to close vote reviewers and second one will close it instantly as duplicate. Am I right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need the button to come back.

That button will actually just take you to the edit screen. What you're supposed to do is *edit your post* to make it clear how your question is different.

Just be sure to be explicit. Don't just say, "This isn't a duplicate", explain why it's not. Do the answers not work for you? Is there another subtle difference? Are the versions so different that the answers aren't relevant? (Make sure you've tried them, just in case.)

The banner can't tell when you've actually explained in an edit how the questions are different, so it just assumes that if you've edited since it appeared, that's what you were doing.

---

To directly answer the question, though, if I remember correctly, the buttons and banner will come back if the question is flagged/voted to close as duplicate again. There's really nothing you, yourself can do short of flagging or voting on it yourself, but I don't see why you'd want to do that if you don't agree your post is a duplicate.

You're correct on half of it, though- The "That solves my problem" button will instantly close your question as a duplicate. The "Explain" button won't show a message, like I said above, it will just take you to the edit screen so you can edit to make your question clearly different, either by expanding on how that question does not solve yours, or by highlighting whatever subtlety you have that makes them different.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have edited the question. Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: I updated to address the additions to your question, though my answer mostly didn't have to change with that edit. Take a look, let me know if it needs clarified in any way.